# How can I give an already running process root permissions?

Tags: linux

I'd like to give an already running process sudo permissions so that it can make certain system calls.  Is this possible?

Comment: I think you have to stop & start the process again ([here's some additional info...](http://unix.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/solaris-l/chown-a-process-59423)...

Comment: That's disappointing.

Comment: it wouldn't be a good idea to just change the effective permissions on a running executable without a way to notify it that it has been done so.  Some applications have interactive support to dynamically raise permissions with a user prompt.

Answer (score -1):

you can also do these by giving the permission for background process to run with sudo permission by

> sudo fg

for foreground and with process name that will be good i think so

Answer (score -1):

You can try using [tee](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/using/tee). There are various examples on the page in the link. I use it when I forgot to type sudo before editing a local file in vim with

```
!w sudo tee %
```

Comment: This is vim specific right?  I was looking for something more generic

Comment: That is a vim specific-example, yes. The examples from the link are not; they run the gamut of apps. Though all of them involved tee and sudo, for some it is not possible after having called the app from the command line.